# How to edit Regex tag?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

How to edit Regex tag.

This is my code:

```
var target="<p><a href="<ers:redirectURL>xxx</ers:redirectURL>" target="_blank">sean</a></p>";

var mc = new Regex("<(\\s*/?\\s*([^\\s/>]+).*?)>").Matches(target);
```

only 5 value.

```
{<p>}
{<a href="<ers:redirectURL>}
{</ers:redirectURL>}
{</a>}
{</p>}
```

How can I get this 6 exact value?

```
{<p>}
{<a}
{<ers:redirectURL>}
{</ers:redirectURL>}
{</a>}
{</p>}
```

please help me how to edit Regex.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse (psuedo-) HTML with a [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/15498)?

Answer (score 1):

For your example this would work:

```
<([^\s<>]+)>?
```

Your requirements are not clear, but this probably has many other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Another working example would be:

```
(</?[a-zA-Z:]*)>?
```